# write thrown exception to file

Tags: java, exception, throws

is it possible to write a thrown exception to a file without using try catch blocks?

for example

```
public static void method() throws Exception, SQLException{
    if(Exception is thrown){
        write Exception to out.txt;
        write SQLException to out.txt;
    }
}
```

or do you have to do:

```
public static void method(){
    try{
        ...
    }catch(Exception ex){
        write ex to file;
    }catch(SQLException sqlex){
        write sqlex to file;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

```
public static void method() throws Exception, SQLException{
    if(Exception is thrown){
        write Exception to out.txt;
        write SQLException to out.txt;
    }
}
```

Where does the Exception come from?

Btw.: You never declare the most abstract exception `Exception` to be thrown. Some RuntimeExceptions can occur nearly everywhere (Nullpointer, OutOfMemory) so it is useless to declare them everywhere. It's just noise.

```
public static void method() throws Exception, SQLException{
    try{
        ...
    }catch(Exception ex){
        write ex to file;
    }catch(SQLException sqlex){
        write sqlex to file;
    }
}
```

But if you catch it, you usually don't throw, and therefore don't declare at all to throw Exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, I don't *think* it's possible.

However, if executed on *nix, you could just [redirect all output to a file](http://www.mathinfo.u-picardie.fr/asch/f/MeCS/courseware/users/help/general/unix/redirection.html) (or just error output).  But that's not a generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `catch` that exception some how. If you catch it and later on decide to write it a file is ok. Given what you have above I would suggest the second way because the if-statement has no way of actually getting the exception.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to catch specific errors within a method is to use a Try/Catch block. However, it is possible to have a class catch all uncaught exceptions - ie anything that doesn't have a Try/Catch around it.

You can write a custom class to implement Java's `UncaughtExceptionHandler` interface.

```
import java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler;

public class CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {
  public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
    /* Write to file here */
  }
}
```

You then need to tell the Java Virtual Machine to redirect uncaught exceptions to your class.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler());
}
```

Comment: You should be careful when doing this as you can break a lot of stuff.

Comment: I don't think you want to use this method.  To reach this handler you'd have to leave the exception uncaught (all exceptions uncaught if you want to have a go at anything thrown).  If you wanted both write an exception to a file and handle the exception condition, you'd be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do it with straight java unless you instrument the byte code (which you can do with an agent and something like [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/)).  You can do it with an aspect, which is easier than the byte code instrumentation approach.  Take [aspectj](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) for example.  An aspect might be:

```
public aspect ExceptionAdvice {

    pointcut allMethods() : execution(* *(..)) && !within(com.test.ExceptionAdvice);

    after() throwing(Exception e) : allMethods() {
        //write to a file or whatever - I'm lazy and just printed the stack
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
}
```

Once you weave this to your application classes, all exceptions thrown will pass through the join point here.  I just printed the stack but you can log it to a file or do whatever you want.  When the join point completes, the exception continues to be thrown so the calling code has a chance to handle it.  Obviously, you need to change the pointcut definition to suit your classes but this is the general idea.

Comment: You gotta love AOP to handle things like this!

Answer (score 0):

In the second block you already catched the exception, so no need for throws Exception, SqlException.

An exception is detected on a regular line of code, so you can't add an if to each and every one. Yes, try/catch(write) is the only way.

Unless ... you use if/else instead of exception handling

Answer (score 0):

You will need to catch the exception and rethrow it.

```
public static void method() throws Exception, SQLException{
    try{
        ...
    }
    catch(SQLException sqlex){
        write sqlex to file;
        throw ex;
    } 
    catch(Exception ex){
        write ex to file;
        throw ex;
    }
}
```